# Can't run cron file with docker - compose what I can do?

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, cron

I use Django and postgres to them, I wrote a script that scrapes data and writes to the database and another that dumps. And these scripts should run at a certain time, as if in the logs I see that it is raised, but when I run it, it does not work

PS C:\Users\komar\django-scraper-6> docker exec -it scrap bash
root@0296ba2fb7f3:~/django_scraper# supervisorctl status
cron                             RUNNING   pid 9, uptime 0:09:37
server                           EXITED    Feb 15 10:26 AM
root@0296ba2fb7f3:~/django_scraper# supervisorctl start server
server: started
root@0296ba2fb7f3:~/django_scraper# supervisorctl status
cron                             RUNNING   pid 9, uptime 0:11:02
server                           EXITED    Feb 15 10:37 AM

dockerfile

```
FROM python:latest

WORKDIR /root/django_scraper/


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron supervisor

COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./app ./app

COPY configs/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

COPY configs/cronfile /etc/cron.d/cronfile

RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/cronfile

ENTRYPOINT /usr/bin/supervisord
```

cronfile

```
# START CRON JOB LIST
0 12 * * * python /root/django_scraper/app/scrap_file.py >> /tmp/postgres_dump.log 2>&1
0 13 * * * python /root/django_scraper/app/db_dump.py
# END CRON JOB LIST
```

my repo https://github.com/yurakomarnitskyi/django-scraper

dockerfile

```
FROM python:latest

WORKDIR /root/django_scraper/


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron supervisor

COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./app ./app

COPY configs/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

COPY configs/cronfile /etc/cron.d/cronfile

RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/cronfile

ENTRYPOINT /usr/bin/supervisord
```

cronfile

```
# START CRON JOB LIST
0 12 * * * python /root/django_scraper/app/scrap_file.py >> /tmp/postgres_dump.log 2>&1
0 13 * * * python /root/django_scraper/app/db_dump.py
# END CRON JOB LIST
```

my repo:  https://github.com/yurakomarnitskyi/django-scraper

Comment: From my experience cron simply does not work inside containers, quick solution is to add a cron on the host server and execute docker run of your docker image .. second option not so quick is to setup a celery system.